# Previous Page Referral To My Website

Tags: javascript, php, url, referrer

I am trying to return a value depending on which is the previous page the user came from.

I have looked at PHP with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`but this is no longer supported.

I have looked at JavaScript with

```
function sourcePrevious(){

    if (document.referrer.search('https?://(.*)google.([^/?]*)') === 0) {
        return 'Google';
    } else if (document.referrer.search('https?://(.*)yahoo.([^/?]*)') === 0) {
        return 'Yahoo';
    } else if (document.referrer.search('https?://(.*)bing.([^/?]*)') === 0) {
        return 'Bing';
    }else if (document.referrer.search('https?://(.*)facebook.([^/?]*)') === 0) {
        return 'Facebook';
    }else {
        return 'Other';
    }

}

alert(sourcePrevious());
```

Which works in part, for Google, Yahoo & Facebook its working but for Bing and Twitter this is not the same case.

Can anyone point me in a direction of a method to do this or let me know how to get the JavaScript function to work for all sources.

Thanks!

Comment: It works for me. I have used Bing, opened the random page and `document.referrer.search('https?://(.*)bing.([^/?]*)')` in a console returned 0.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not supported? That is not true FYI. But not all user agents set it. Please add the browser and PHP versions you are using.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast!

I found this on php.net
'HTTP_REFERER'
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Min is also returning 0 for both twitter and bing so I can't separate these elements.

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE SOLVED THE TWITTER PROBLEM

```
(document.referrer.search('https?://(.*)t.([^/?]*)') === 0)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!